# Ruby - how to clear a variable content?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I guess it's written somewhere but maybe I use the wrong keywords...

I'd simply like to clear a content in a variable after pressing a button (via Shoes):

```
Shoes.app do

    @text = edit_line


    button "ok" do 
        @text = @text.text
        para @text
        @text.clear

        if @text.nil?  #to check if variable is empty
            para "empty"
        else 
            para "not empty"
        end
    end


end
```

for anybody who has problems to understand what this program is good for: This is just a test to find out how to clear content of a variable. Because I'd like to make something like a palindrom-tester and the part of clearing what's inside of Variable. Because if I say to shoes at the end of the button-progress

```
....
@text = ""   # instead of @text.clear
```

the whole program is not working anymore... Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check if the String is empty: `@text.empty?`

Comment: it checks if the value of the variable is nil. and nil literally stands for nothing. this is so because internally the variable only contains a pointer(reference) to the object which holds your data (in your example a string) a string itself can be empty (which string.empty? tests for) but a nil value means that is a reference to nothing (so no longer a String)